# How to Iterate Over a List in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a simple for loop to iterate over a list of various dates. For each item in the list, I exclude the timezone by taking only the first 10 characters. However, when I pass the object to my template only the first value in the list is being returned for all values.

views.py

```
for opportunity in opportunities:
    temp = opportunity['expectedCloseDate']
    time = temp[:10]

context { 'time': time }
return render(request, 'website', context)
```

template.html

```
<div class="control is-inline-flex">
    <input class="input" name="close_date" id="close_date" type="date" value="{{ time }}" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: With a `for` loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem a `for` loop to iterate over `time`?

Comment: your `time` here is just the *last* value that appeared in the `opportinities` list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so I should place each value for `time` in a list and iterate through that in my template?

Comment: I realy advice against doing that. You better use a form here. It will also remove a lot of boilerplate to convert between Python objects and HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a list of `times`:

```
times = [opportunity['expectedCloseDate'][:10] for opportunity in opportunities]
return render(request, 'website', {'times': times})
```

and then iterate over this in your template:

```
<div class="control is-inline-flex">
    {% for time in times %}
        <input class="input" name="close_date" id="close_date" type="date" value="{{ time }}" disabled>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

That being said, it looks like you are building a form manually. It is usually better to use Django's [**`Form`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-django-form-class) here.

If you want to loop concurrently over two lists, you can make use of `zip`, like:

```
times = [opportunity['expectedCloseDate'][:10] for opportunity in opportunities]
opps_times = zip(opportunities, times)
return render(request, 'website', {'opps_times': opps_times})
```

and render this with:

```
{% for opportunity, time in opps_times %}
    <!-- ... -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have another `for` loop which populates some number of input fields for `time`. When I do this, every value of `time` in `times` is being rendered in each individual input field instead of 1:1. How can I specify one value per input?

Comment: @garmars: you should get the `<input>` for the `time` out of the second `{% for ... %}` loop, such that  it is rendered once per `time`.

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand...I have something like: `{% for opportunity in opportunities %} {% for time in times %} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}`...so the loop for time is nested, is this why every value is being returned instead of 1 for every `<input>`? I am having to do this because of the format for `type=date` does not accept a timezone and so then for every opportunity in opportunities, I need to get the date and strip the timezone from each value and then pass it back to my template.

Comment: @garmars: then you will need to use a `zip` instead.

Comment: thanks! Worked like a charm...glad you could help me learn a thing or two!

Answer (score 1):

You are always overwriting time in each iteration. Try something like

```py
time = []
for opportunity in opportunities:
    temp = opportunity['expectedCloseDate']
    time.append(temp[:10])

context = { 'time': time }
return render(request, 'website', context)
```